# In "Modern C++ Design" why does PrototypeFactoryUnit::GetPrototype have to call DoGetPrototype?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In Andrei Alexandrescu's book, "Modern C++ Design", why does `PrototypeFactoryUnit::GetPrototype` have to call the friend function `DoGetPrototype`? Why can't it just set the passed-in pointer to the prototype itself? The same thing has been done with the `PrototypeFactoryUnit::SetPrototype` and the `DoSetPrototype` functions.

Comment: While many have read this book you should give a more specific example. Show the entire abstract factory for starters.

Answer (score 2):

Some context!

```
template <class, class Base>
class PrototypeFactoryUnit: public Base {
public:
  typedef typename Base::ProductList::Head AbstractProduct;

  friend void DoGetPrototype(const PrototypeFactoryUnit& me,
                             AbstractProduct*& pPrototype)
  {
    pPrototype = me.pPrototype_;
  }

  template <class U>
  void GetPrototype(U*& p) {
    return DoGetPrototype(*this, p);
  }
private:
  AbstractProduct* pPrototype_;
};
```

(though it did give me the opportunity to clean up the dust on this one...)

Because `GetPrototype` is template, it can be instantiated with many different types. Then, overload resolution will come into play!

For example, I write a `DoGetPrototype(...& me, DerivedProduct*& p)` and then say:

```
DerivedProduct* p =0;
factory.GetPrototype(p);
```

Then, **my** overload is called.

Therefore, this is a point of customization: a static dispatch similar equivalent to its runtime counterpart of a `virtual` function with a default implementation.

Comment: If you wrote a new DoGetPrototype(...& me, DerivedProduct*& p), since pPrototype_ is private, you'd still have to modify PrototypeFactoryUnit to make the new DoGetPrototype a friend of the class. Is that correct? Couldn't we simply specialise GetPrototype itself for various cases like this?  

void GetPrototype(AbstractProduct *&p);  

void GetPrototype(DerivedProduct *&p);  

Wouldn't it result in the same thing?

Comment: @Ashley: right... This would only work if one replaced `me` by the prototype itself. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

If you will write simply

```
void GetPrototype(AbstractProduct*& p)
    { p = pPrototype_; }
```

where `AbstractProduct` is `PrototypeFactoryUnit`'s template parameter, then only `GetPrototype` specialized with last `ConcreteFactory`'s `TList` type will be visible.

It's because `ConcreteFactory` linearly inherits specializations of `PrototypeFactoryUnit` for every `TList`'s type and all previous versions of `GetPrototype` will be hidden by name.